# Facebook Watch Episodes API

Tags: facebook

Are there any Facebook APIs to retrieve the episodes of a show from Facebook Watch?
E.G. Get all the series and episodes in those series of https://www.facebook.com/sacredliesshow/

The closest I can find is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video-list/#Reading but it's not clear how I should deduce the  `{video-list-id}` from the page https://www.facebook.com/sacredliesshow/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get all video lists (including their IDs and names) for a page (based on ID) from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/video_lists/

That specific page's ID seems to be "454309158359123" (Extracted from the page's header section). However, given that the endpoint mentioned above is private I don't think you'll be able to use this if you don't actually own the page or have login access to it. Probably also why you can't just get the ID of video lists from their website by inspecting the source.